# how to access billing address element in one page check out module in magento?

Tags: php, codeigniter, magento-1.7

In one page check out module when  am calling getCustomerBllAddr() function.it fatching complete address. i want to get diffrent element of address like name,city etc.
how can i get this?
how to use format function f possible?

Answer (score 0):

With the object returned by the `getCustomerBillingAddress` method you can do the following:

```
$street = $address->getStreet();//or $address->getData('street')
$country = $address->getCountryId();//or $address->getData('country_id');
```

Basically any element from the `$_data` member of the address can be called like this.

**[EDIT]**
You can get the customer billing address like this:

```
$address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()
```

Then you can work do `$address->getStreet()` and other.

Comment: this error is comming:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /var/www/shop/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/onepagecheckout/onepage/billing.phtml
any other option to access?

Comment: What does the address object look like? The one returned by `getCustomerBllAddr()` as you said.

Comment: output:
string(66) "abhi1 agarwal, c-3/23 rajouri garden, new delhi, delhi 110048, India" // 
<br>came from calling this code: getCustomerBillAddr(){$address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
            $addr =  $address->format('oneline');
            return $addr;
        }}

Comment: Oh...I misunderstood your question. Sorry for that. I've updated the answer. I hope I have it right this time.

Comment: thanx a lot!!!! now its working perfectly by using:
$this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();

Comment: By using that you get the current billing address. With `getPrimaryBillingAddress` you get the main billing address of the customer even if he doesn't use it at checkout. There is a difference.